# What does it mean to subvert a trope?

Tags: tropes

Recently, I've been seeing a lot of discussions about works that subvert a given trope. I think I have an understanding of what this means (from context) but can someone offer a clear definition or explanation?

Comment: There's some explanation and examples, of course, on [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SubvertedTrope). [Obvious warning, TV Tropes link if you're trying to be productive.]

Answer (score 14):

A writing "trope," generally speaking, is a commonly used thematic element.  The term is sometimes used interchangeably with "cliche" or "stereotype."  To subvert it is to make deliberate use of it, but with a change that undercuts or reverses the typical meaning.

For example, the "Man in Black" turning out to be the hero of *The Princess Bride* subverts the trope of the hero dressing in white, the villain in black.

Comment: I think a better example would be "Frozen", subverting several very classic Disney tropes - "Evil Queen" or "True Love at First Sight". When the trope in question has a continuity, and is switched upside down, first building, then shattering our expectations with an amazing outcome - that's a typical subversion. Don't confuse with *averting* a trope, that is doing that reversal since moment one. In The Princess Bride we learn "the man in black" is not an antagonist early enough I wouldn't count it as an actual subversion.

Comment: Example of *averted* in "Frozen" would be Anna not falling in love with Kristoff, just remaining friends with him - the classic "romance forged by fire" trope fizzling with no spectacular effects, instead of either being brought to conclusion (love) or subverted (say, the two becoming sworn enemies at the end.)

Comment: @SF I think you're underselling the Man in Black.  He's introduced in an antagonistic role, which he inhabits for a fairly substantial portion of the narrative, and his costume, including the mask, is meant to be threatening. In point of fact, he actually *is* the "Dread Pirate Roberts" at least nominally. He's also a deliberate counterpoint to another subverted trope, the handsome prince as rescuer of the princess (years before *Frozen* did the same thing).

Comment: @SF. Anna and Kristoff not falling in love would have been an averted trope, if that's what had happened, which it wasn't.

Comment: Another subverted trope in Frozen is, I think, the love interest turning into a bad guy. Is it still a subverted trope if it's another trope (in this case Face-Heel turn)?

Comment: @stannius: sometimes one trope is a subversion of another :)

Comment: The villain dressing in black was pretty much a Dead Horse Trope by the time *The Princess Bride* was written (and filmed). There were enough characters dressed in black (or otherwise dark colours), sometimes even masked, who were heroes (Zorro and Batman spring to mind immediately, who had both been around for decades) that "the good guy dresses in black; surprise!" isn't much of a surprise.

Answer (score 5):

A trope is a cliché setup; of any kind, that audiences have come to expect.

An example in a commercial is the great looking guy catching sight of a jaw-dropping girl, dropping everything to approach her as she smiles, and walking past her to the new car, or picture of a stacked burger, or to the nerdy guy with the new iPhone.

Another commercial: A man hears music blasting in his front yard; cut to a teen holding a boom box up, looking to the window on the second floor; cut back to man with his iphone punching a button, cut to teen -- lawn sprinklers come on full blast and the teen is surprised and runs for cover.

In Deep Blue Sea, they subvert a racist trope: LL Cool J plays a black cook in a film where nearly every main character gets eaten by genetically engineered clever sharks. The racist trope, built up over numerous movies in the previous decades, is that black characters die first. (This is racist and was not invented or ever used by ME, please hold any angry comments.) However, in DBS although Samuel L. Jackson *does* get eaten by a shark, LL Cool J the lowly cook comes close but always escapes by wit and action; in fact he ends up one of the two survivors. (But Samuel L. Jackson breaks the same racist trope in Die Hard with a Vengeance; as a black store owner reluctantly caught up in Bruce Willis' bid to stop a lethal heist; but Jackson's character (Zeus Carver) ends up a brave and useful sidekick that survives the entire ordeal).

Broke Back Mountain is subverting the trope of Cowboy Masculinity.

Buffy the Vampire Slayer subverts the trope of the helpless teen cheerleader that is typically an eye candy cardboard character.

In the series Heroes, Hayden Panettiere played Claire Bennett; another cheerleader type that looks like a petite, beautiful, helpless teen. But she has unlimited magical healing powers and (for a few seasons at least) apparently cannot be killed; making her one of the most formidable fighters of all heroes.

The Truth About Cats and Dogs is a romantic comedy that subverts a trope: Unlike other romantic comedies in which the female romantic interest tends to be beautiful (younger Meg Ryan, Julia Roberts), here the love interest is a short, plain girl (played by Janeane Garofolo).

In the series Psych, the "Sherlockian" detective (uses hyper-observational powers) subverts the Sherlock trope by being an immature, lazy, get-rich-quick liar. (The Sherlock Holmes trope is more like the series Elementary; but **they** then subvert that trope by making sidekick Watson a female doctor, and often the smartest person in the room except for Sherlock -- and sometimes beating even him to the punch.)

In The Mentalist, the Sherlockian detective subverts the Sherlock trope by being a carny con man. (also female sidekick and eventual love interest.)

In the series Monk, the Sherlockian detective subverts the Sherlock trope by being an obsessive compulsive afraid of just about everything (in advertising, the Defective Detective; although they were not the first to use it).

Subverting a trope is just writing against any "formula" the audience has come to expect (even subconsciously) from a genre; be it horror, romantic comedy, action/adventure, war or drama. It can be a minor part of the movie or a major component of it. It is a way of injecting surprise into the work. But it can be overdone or come off as flat or unsatisfying: Some tropes are founded in human nature, and often if audiences cannot identify with the character violating the trope, the story will fall flat.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good example of subverting a trope and then subverting the subversion: in the original *Mass Effect* game trilogy, one of the alien species you encounter is the asari. Asari are the stereotypical beautiful all-female humanoid alien species that have long been a cliché in science fiction, especially when one of the ones you first encounter on one of the first side-missions is, for all the talking around about it, a glorified prostitute, and soon you find more as strippers at a low-life bar. So that's following the standard hypersexual Green Skinned Alien Space Babe (although they're mostly blue, but you get the idea), just like the portrayals of the Orion women in the original *Star Trek*.

Okay, now subversion: although you see asari as stereotypical initially, as the games go on, most of the asari you meet subvert that stereotype. Liara is a shy, geeky archeologist and a virgin. You meet asari commandos, who are deadly opponents, and asari politicians and diplomats and business people and scientists, and so on and so forth. The Green Skinned Alien Space Babe trope is subverted and although the player can still encounter asari strippers in bars, that's not what you think of the asari as. Now there's several new tropes in play, one of which is that you shouldn't think of the asari as just sexy aliens who will have sex with anyone of any species.

Then they subvert the subversion: you meet one asari matriarch who complains that young asari spend too much time whoring it up around the galaxy. You meet another asari who is a ruthless crime boss who seized control of a space station by having her subordinates sleep their way into the confidence of her rivals before she took them out. And you find out there's a quirk of asari biology and reproduction that makes it desirable for them to mate outside their species. In short, the stereotypes people have about the asari are somewhat justified, as the asari themselves admit (and some take advantage of).

So there is an example of subverting a trope: the game set up the player to believe the asari were following a standard SF trope, then subverted it, then went and subverted that by justifying the original trope.

Note that the original Green Skinned Alien Space Babes, the Orions, likewise subverted their own trope on *Enterprise* when it was revealed that the females emitted pheromones that controlled their males and could affect other species. They intentionally played up their role as simple sex objects in order to manipulate others.